# How to push my footer below the right column menu's

Tags: html, css, css-float

My menu's at the right column are bigger than my newsarticles.
This is causing that the menu is overlapping my footer.

How do I get my footer pushed down in the same proportion as my right column?

Any help would be appreciated

website: http://www.e107webdesign.nl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your left and right column should be in the same DIV, and footer should go under that div

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">...</div>
  <div id="right">...</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks playcat,

I found out. They where in the same DIV, only the sidebar was set to position absolute and a left margin of 593.
Now I have changed it to position: relative with a margin-left 0

This solved the problem.

Comment: Oh, my bad :). Well, I hope it helped a little bit, even if to point you to a place where u saw I was wrong, and fixed things :)

Comment: Thats exactly right! Sometimes people point you a little to the right direction! Thanks!